# jquery and json send values error (Unexpected token b)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, zend-framework2

no, for example in the next case
the error is SyntaxError: Unexpected token b listados:229 why?

```
   response = '{"name":"John"}';
   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);


   $.ajax({

   url:urlform,
   dataType:'json',
   type:'POST',
   data:obj,
   async: false,
   contentType: 'application/json',
   success: function(data) {
    alert('ok');
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
   console.log("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);

     },
    });
  });
```

why?

Comment: It seems that your server response are not valid JSON. Can you dump it?

Answer (score -1):

you have extra `});` at the end as well as remove the trailing `,` in error callback...

I see no error in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/8gehj/

Note: you need to provide responseData as well in your question...

Comment: Please comment if you have a question, don't write an answer for that.